# Error de Sintaxis - Select en Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> EDITO SOLUCIÓN

Sorry por haceros perder el tiempo... El problema era que estaba importando:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
```

en vez de:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
```

Me ha costado encontrarla por el tipo de error... Daba error de sintaxis en la query y ni se me ocurrió comprobar eso cuidado cuando Netbeans importa automaticamente.

Y tambien...

```
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

No hay que pasarle sql ahí... se le pasa antes

> DUDA

Deberá ser una tontería pero llevo un rato bueno detrás y no consigo arreglarlo. ¿El `select` esta bien hecho verdad?

```
public static boolean login(String user_name, String password) {

    boolean status = false;
    int size = 0;

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName LIKE ? and password LIKE ?";

    Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        preparedStatement = conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user_name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, password);

        System.out.println(preparedStatement);

        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);

        if (rs != null) {
            rs.last(); 
            size = rs.getRow();
        }

        status = (size == 1);

        preparedStatement.close();
        conexion.cerrarConexion();

        return status;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }

}
```

> ERROR #1

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? and password LIKE ?' at line 1
```

Si uso:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = '?' and password = '?'";
```

> ERROR #2

```
ERROR:java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

Si uso:

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "%"+user_name+"%");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "%"+password+"%");
```

> ERROR #1 con un `sout` de la consulta.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = ? and password = ? ------ com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@7b0636ec: SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = '%jjh%' and password = '%sdf%'

ERROR:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? and password = ?' at line 1
```

Comment: checa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44373883/5215609

Comment: Por favor Tygreton, pon la respuesta en el sitio de respuesta, y no en la misma pregunta

Answer (score 0):

No lo está. Se supone que haces like sobre un campo VARCHAR, así que debes usar <del>las comillas simples para indicar a qué se debe parecer el valor del campo para salir en las filas resultado</del> los símbolos que le indican a la consulta que la consulta es un LIKE. El preparedStatement no necesita comillas simples y ponerlas hace que procese el símbolo como un literal.

Algo como

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName LIKE ? and password LIKE ?
...
preparedStatement.setString(1, "%"+user_name+"%");
....
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2857417/236345)

Comment: Ahora me da esto... Como si no identificara que las '?' son parámetros a sustituir. java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: Edité la respuesta porque parece que me faltaba el café de la tarde. Perdón

Comment: Sigue habiendo un error de sintaxis. He comprobado que no haya caracteres especiales u ocultos en el codigo... No se que puede pasar. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Puede probar a poner tu query sin `LIKE`:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = ? and password = ?";
```

Y despues ya utilizar tus variables:

```
  preparedStatement.setString(1, user_name);
  preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
```

Comment: Eso da exactamente el mismo error que he puesto arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizandolo asi

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "'%"+user_name+"%'");
```

preparedStatement.setString(2, "'%"+password+"'%");

con comillas entre %% (no recuerdo si afuera o dentro)

Comment: Por favor edita y explica

Comment: No... usando las comillas antes y despues del % sigue dando el mismo error de Sintaxis

Answer (score -2):

Deberías probar pasando los campos que van ha hacer el filtro directamente dentro de la sentencia sql y no a través del `preparedStatement`, intenta esto

> String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName LIKE '"+user_name+"' and password LIKE '"+password +"'";

Si esta consulta es para el login, te aconsejo usar el `=` y no el `LIKE`, ejemplo

> String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = '"+user_name+"' and password = '"+password +"'";

Comment: Y por qué pasar los valores directos? Cuando la intención con sentencias preparadas es proteger contra SQL Injection?

Comment: Los valores no los voy a pasar directamente. Para eso uso el PS.